# The existence of way from $(0,0)$ to $(n,n)$

Tags: combinatorics

Let $n$ be a positive integer and $D$ be a convex area on the plane containing $(0,0)$ and $(n,n)$. There is a robot at the origin $(0,0)$, and there're some emitters that can send signals to the robot. The working principle of the robot is as follows:

$(a)$ On day zero, the robot is turned on.

$(b)$ The robot will shut down once it leaves the convex area $D$.

$(c)$ On the $k$-th day ($k\in \{1,2,\cdots,2n\}$), as long as the robot is powered on, it waits for a signal from the emitter, and do the following as the next day approaches: If any signal was received on the first day, move one bit North, otherwise move one bit East.
On day $0$, you received $n$ emitter $R_1,R_2,\cdots,R_n$, and for each emitter $R_i$, you are notified in advance that on certain days you are strictly prohibited from using $R_i$. Fortunately, you found that for each $i\in \{1,2,\cdots,n\}$, in the next $2n$ days, you can use only the emitter $R_i$ to move the robot from $(0,0)$ to $(n,n)$.

Prove that in the next $2n$ days, you can move the robot from $(0,0)$ to $(n,n)$ so that each emitter $R_i$ is used once.
$$$$
This problem becomes obvious if we discard the "stay in convex area $D$" requirement (By using Hall's marriage theorem), what we need is to deal with the convex case. Since convex means that any two points in D will imply that the corresponding segment is still inside $D$. I think this can be somewhat solved by induction but I didn’t figure it out. Is there any suggestions or hints about this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but your presentation isn't clear for me. How in particular is "decided" the emission of  each controller each day ? I don't understand the vague "on certain days" ; is the refusal to take into account emitter $E_1$ on day 1, emitter $E_2$ on day 2, etc. ? Please give a complete simple example.

Comment: About "convex area" : do you mean plainly the square with vertices (0,0),(0,n),(n,n),(n,0) ?

Comment: For example, pick $n=2$, emitter $R_1$ is forbidden to use in day $1,3$, emitter $R_2$ is forbidden to use in day $2,4$, with the $D$ being the convex area surrounded by $(0,0),(0,1),(1,2),(2,2),(2,1),(1,0),(0,0)$. This is legal since for $R_1$ we can use it in day $2,4$, for $R_2$ we can use it on day $1,3$. We can also use $R_2$ on day $1$ and $R_1$ in day $4$ to move the robot from $(0,0)$ to $(2,2)$, all three cases make sure the robot is always in $D$.

Comment: You've told us to prove this, so I'm assuming there are some rules that I can't read from the question. Here are some questions to try to clarify them:$\tag*{}$
1. What is the rule prevents us from prohibiting all emitters every day. Is there only one day prohibited for each emitter? Or maybe one emitter prohibited for each day?$\tag*{}$
2. What is the rule that prevents us from choosing the D = convex hull of (0,0), (1,0), (n,n-1), (n,n). This region only contains the (i,i) for each i=0,...,n and the points (1,0) and (n,n-1), so it's impossible to get to (n,n) with only N and E steps.

Comment: Each emitter can be prohibited for many days, it can be 0 days, 1 day, 2 days or even every day (although it can be proved to be impossible, this is just an example); For the second problem I’ve already assumed that “for each ∈{1,2,⋯,}, in the next 2 days, you can use only the emitter  to move the robot from (0,0) to (,)”, so the area $D$ must be not that bad.

Comment: You haven't said me yes or no to my question: why can't you restrict your attention to the square with vertices (0,0),(0,n),(n,n),(n,0) (and its interior points of course) ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Sorry for late reply, no I don't mean the square with vertices $(0,0),(0,n),(n,n),(n,0)$. Consider the convex hull of all points of $D$, here we say $D$ is convex means that $D$ contains all the points inside the convex hull and on the boundary of convex hull. For example (mentioned in earlier reply), when $n=2$ then $D=\{(0,0),(0,1),(1,2),(2,2),(2,1),(1,0),(1,1)\}$ is a convex area.